# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
NS_from = int(input())
print(type(NS_from))
#тут выводит int
while NS_from > 36 or NS_from < 2:
#а здесь int превратился в None
```

После проверки условия в цикле вылезает ошибка, что тип NS_from - None, хотя до проверки пишет, что int

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Вот полный код

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[32]:
while True:
    NScomm = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    res = 0
    k = 0
    k1 = 0
    k2 = 0
    NS_fromns = list('0123456789')
    NS_tons = []
    res = []
    while k1 != 1:
        try:
            NS_from = int(input())
            print(NS_from)
            print(type(NS_from))
            while NS_from > 36 or NS_from < 2:
                 NS_from = print('Введенное число находится вне диапозона от 2 до 36, введите число заново или введите ноль чтобы выйти из программы')
                 if NS_from == 0:
                    break
            if NS_from == 0:
                break
            k1 = 1
        except:
            raise
            #print('Основание системы счисления должно быть целым числом, введите основание заново или введите ноль для выхода из программы')
    if NS_from == 0:
            #break
            pass

    while k != 1:
        number = int(input())
        if number == 0:
            break
        try:
            number = int(str(number), NS_from)
            k = 1
        except:
            print('В веденном числе есть знаки не входящие в его систему счисления, введите число заново или введите ноль для выхода из программы')
    if number == 0:
        break
    tmp = number
    while k2 != 1:
        try:
            NS_to = int(input())
            if NS_to == 0:
                break
        except:
            print('Основание системы счисления должно быть целым числом, введите число заново или введите ноль для выхода из программы')
    if NS_to == 0:
        break
    while NS_to > 36 or NS_to < 2:
        if NS_to == 0:
            break
        NS_to = int(input('Веденное число находится вне диапозона от 2 до 36, ведите число заново или введите ноль для выхода из программы\n'))
        if NS_to == 0:
            break
    if NS_to == 0:
        break
    for i in range(0, NS_to):
        NS_tons.append(list(NScomm)[i])
    if NS_from == NS_to:
        print('\n\n')
        print(number)
    if NS_to != 10:
        if number <= len(NS_tons):
            print(NS_tons[number])
        else:
            while not (tmp < NS_to):
                tmp = (number // NS_to) * NS_to
                res.append(NS_tons[number - tmp])
                number = tmp // NS_to
                if number < NS_to and number != 0:
                    res.append(NS_tons[int(number)])
        res.reverse()
        del res[0]
        print('\n\n')
        try:
            print(int(''.join(res)), 'int')
        except:
            print(''.join(res), 'str')
    else:
        print(number, 'int')
```

Comment: Добавьте полный код. Ошибка в цикле.

Comment: Ничего не превращается, всё работает нормально, указанной вами ошибки нет

Comment: @andreymal Я думаю ошибка в цикле. Надеюсь выложит полный код.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica добавил весь код

Comment: `NS_from = print(...)`

Comment: @extrn благодарю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что вместо

```
NS_from = print('Введенное число находится вне диапозона от 2 до 36, введите число заново или введите ноль чтобы выйти из программы')
```

должно быть

```
NS_from = int(input('Введенное число находится вне диапозона от 2 до 36, введите число заново или введите ноль чтобы выйти из программы'))
```